# how to use facebook connect in local host

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Each developer is running IIS on his own machine. We all sit in separate physical location.
One developer develops the code using:  http://localhost:8054/connectToFacebook.aspx
another developer develops the code using: http://localhost:80/virtualDirectory/connectToFacebook.aspx
etc.

I'd like the Facebook Connect authentication to work for all the developers.
Generally, the connect mechanism (login button with ajax dialog) does not work from localhost, as it requires a domain name.

Is it possible to make the Connect mechanism work - when watching the webpage from localhost? (or must I run the webpage be a publicly accessible domain name like dyndns?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [tutorial](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website&referringTitle=Documentation) shows you how to use the c# sdk w/ localhost. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you
i find this helpful for my local host issue.but this explanation for mvc development i also need this type of document for asp.net webforms

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to make every dev on the team use the same url.

if u r using fb c# sdk, u can continue to use differnt url by implementing your own IFacebookApplication and depending on the request url change the appid and appsecret.